# Windows 7 computer boot issues

Tags: windows-7, reboot

My father's computer (a frankenstein) will not start.  It was rebooted by a software update i think and now, I boot the thing, it comes to a selection screen with two options, start computer normally, and delete restoration data and go to system startup menu.  The keyboard isn't working to select an option much less choose one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the key board works in bios (google how to get into bios menu on your pc). If it does not work there then most likely it is a hardware issue. 
If it works in bios ok, firstly Try connecting the keyboard directly to the pc if it is plugged in via a hub. If it does not help try booting from a rescue disk and do a virus scan.